# incrementing HTML numbers with the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am working on a Rock Paper Scissors game and I am having some trouble incrementing the score when a win condition is met.

this is my HTML score that I want to increment

```
        <h1>you : <span id = "playerScore">0</span></h1>
```

```
let playersScore = document.getElementById('playerScore');
function playersChoosesRock(){
    if (playersChoice == ' Rock ' && computerChoice == ' Paper '){
        playersScore.innerHTML = ++;
        console.log('YOU LOSE');        
}
```

This is my javascript code the player selects Rock and the computer selects Paper I want to increment my 0 in the HTML if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

This is the error that pops up when I attempt to make the innerHTML = '1'

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
```

Comment: `= ++;` is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Just confused the meaning of  `I want to increment my 0`. Does that means you want to make the score increase by 1?

Comment: Just use `++`, not `= ++`

Comment: Yes i just want to increase the score by 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant assign innerHtml to an operator because it takes a value.
You can add a counter in your JS and pass its value to innerHtml or innerText.

Check this example :

**index.html**

```html
<h1>you <span id="playerScore">0</span></h1>
<button id="button">click</button>
```

**app.js**

```js
let playerScore = document.getElementById("playerScore");
let button = document.getElementById("button");

let score = 0;

playerScore.innerHTML = score;

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  score++;
  playerScore.innerHTML = score;
});
```

Comment: Actually I put that code in a separate function and just had the functioned called when the condition was met so thank you.

Comment: i have made an example so you can see how to achieve your code